# Add class to dynamically generated element with css

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I suspect this isn't possible, but am looking for confirmation.  I have a series of image elements that are added as id's to a div.  I'm trying to attach another small image to the first one.  Because the container varies in width based on the user's game content, attaching it to the container hasn't yielded consistent results. My image is stored as a class in the main css file.

Is there a way to use ::before to attach a class to an element that is dynamically generated?

I'm deeply discouraged by my manager from using an javascript for this particular task.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a class using css....

But you could use the :before psuedo to show the image you're trying to add.

```css
div#this-id {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
div#this-id:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(image-folder/image/jpg) no-repeat 0 0 #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="this-id"></div>
```

Comment: It looks like a great answer, and I'm going to upvote it, but I have to use the class, per company standards.

Comment: then replace the id with the image class, this would work in the same way

Comment: I mean, the image is stored as a class, and that is how it must be referenced in this codebase, per company standards.

Comment: ah I see, then you're out of luck with CSS I'm afraid.

Comment: That's what I thought/was hoping to be wrong about :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add a class name with CSS, but you can just use `selector:pseudo-class` for it, example below, to use `.container:before` as a real class name.

```css
.container:before {
    content: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" />
</div>
```

**Fiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dh6ynq32/ (with some custom styles)

Answer (score -1):

You can use in `jQuery` something like `$( your_element ).addClass( your_class)`

Comment: My entire issue is that I can't use Javascript for this task, unless it's an absolute last resort.

Comment: Oh wow my bad, I read encouraged, sorry. Then yeah, try using CSS as posted above but I really think using JS is the best way to go.

Comment: I agree it would be the best way to go.  My boss doesn't.